# NodeJS Node-Fetch Sending multipart stops before sending file stream

Tags: node.js, forms, express, multipartform-data, node-fetch

I have a NodeJS/Express/Node-Fetch stack that attempts to receive a file via a multi-part upload from a browser and forward that request with little adjustments to a Java Spring Boot server.

My routing snippet is below. I have verified that the file gets uploaded and the Multer plugin saves the file in $CWD/uploads as mentioned below. (I wish I knew how to reliably use a temp directory instead of the root, but that's not my major problem.)

My problems are:
var testSpreadsheetStream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path); // Sets testSpreadsheetStream to a valid read stream

but the formData seems to be not reading the file. The Java side that receives this issues an HTTP 500 and has an IO exception mentioned below. When I step through the code in a debugger, the node-fetch returns immediately and goes to the next() statement instead of waiting for it to complete. I wish I could force it to be synchronous. So I know the NodeJS code is making contact with the Java based log messages consistent with each browser request, it's just that it's getting substantially less, or none at all, of the file I'm trying to send.

```
2021-03-05 00:26:39 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:960)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.mycompany.myproject.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at com.mycompany.myproject.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2932)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3232)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:84)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2884)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1253)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1196)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:729)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1084)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:572)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:596)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:614)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:865)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:845)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
2021-03-05 00:26:39 DEBUG o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4497fed9
2021-03-05 00:26:39 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException] with root cause
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1253)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1196)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:729)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1084)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:572)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:596)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:614)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:865)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:845)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2884)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3232)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

```
    var multer = require('multer');
    // var spreadsheetFileMiddleware = multer({storage: multer.memoryStorage});
    var spreadsheetFileMiddleware = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

    app.post('/bluecost/spreadsheet/upload/*', ensureAuthenticated,
        function (req, res, next) {
            logger.debug('Route: /bluecost/*: Reached ' + req.originalUrl);
            next();
        },
        spreadsheetFileMiddleware.single('file'),
        (req, res, next) => {
            const url = require('url');
            var spreadsheet_host_url = url.parse(config.spreadsheet_server_host, true);
            spreadsheet_host_url.pathname = req.originalUrl;
            // spreadsheet_host_url.pathname = spreadsheet_host_url.pathname.replace('/bluecost/', '/');
            logger.debug('/spreadsheet-upload: Generating token based on proxyReqOpts.user=' + req.user);
            var spreadsheet_host_url_string = url.format(spreadsheet_host_url);

            logger.info(`@@Route for ${req.originalUrl} Request ${req.method} ${spreadsheet_host_url_string}`);
            var accessToken = generateToken(req.user);
            /**
             * Set bearer token based on code from Sprint-API's lua code
             */
            // req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            logger.debug('Route: /bluecost: adding Authorization: Bearer ' + accessToken);
            var newHeaders = req.headers;
            newHeaders['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
            if (!(isMultipartRequest(req) && req.method === 'PUT' || req.method === 'POST')) {
                console.log('Expecting multipart file request. Content type or method does not match');
            } else {
                console.log('@@ detected multipart form');
                if (req.body && req.body.length>0) {
                    var encodedBodyBuffer = new Buffer(req.body);
                    var encodedBody = encodedBodyBuffer.toString('base64');
                    console.log('@@ MULTIPART Encoded=' + encodedBody);
                    console.log('@@ END MULTIPART');
                }
                var FormData = require('form-data');
                console.log('@@ req.file.path='+req.file.path);
                const formData = new FormData();
                const fs = require('fs');
                var testSpreadsheetStream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path);
                formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path));
                console.log('req headers=' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
                const options = {
                    port: spreadsheet_host_url.port,
                    path: spreadsheet_host_url.pathname,
                    method: req.method,
                    headers: req.headers,
                    body: formData,
                    redirect: true
                };
                const fetch = require('node-fetch');
                fetch(spreadsheet_host_url_string, options).then(r => {
                    console.log('@@ spreadsheet send reached fetch result retrieved');
                    return r.text();
                }).then(fetchText => {
                    console.log('@@ spreadsheet send reached fetch text result retrieved');
                    /*
                    // This code complains that headders can't be set after sending to client
                    res.writeHead(res.statusCode,res.headers);
                    res.send(fetchText);
                    */
                    // res.body=fetchText;
                    console.log('@@ fetchText=' + fetchText);
                    res.status(200).send(fetchText);

                    next();
                }).catch(err => { console.log('Error on spreadsheet send  ' + err) });
                next();
            }
        }
    );
```

Spring Boot endpoint:

```
    @ApiOperation(      
    value = "Upload spreadsheet data file",       
    notes = "Allows you to upload a single file with each request")   

    @PostMapping("/spreadsheet/upload/{filename}")
    public ResponseEntity<HashMap<String,Object>> uploadSpreadsheet(@PathVariable("filename") String filename, @RequestBody MultipartFile file) {
        logger.info("[uploadSpreadsheet][POST][START] - Paramenters: [filename={}]", filename);
        String logErrorTemplate = "[uploadSpreadsheet][POST][ERR] - Details: [status={}, message={}, filename={}, uploader={}]";
```

I believe I've handled this multipart stuff correctly, but how do force node-fetch to send the file? Would it be better to read it into memory and stuff it into FormData rather than using a stream and *hoping* it gets read?

Comment: You're calling `next()` twice, the last one should not be there (out of the `.then` chain) as it is executed _before_ the asynchronous, promisified `fetch` call completes.